# Is there any open source implementation of GeoXACML based access control mechanism for OGC Web Services?

Tags: security, ogc

I am looking for an open source implementation of GeoXACML PEP, PDP to provide access control to my OGC web services. I have already set-up SAML based authentication. I found a non-opensource implementation from Secure Dimensions but I want to know if there is any opensource implementation.